# DataBinnding in angular from popup to parent page using angular material tables

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a sample angular app where I have implemented data binding from popup to parent page and from parent page back again to popup.

When I am clicking on save button in my popup window the data rows moved from first table to second are binded and displayed in the data table in my parent page.

But second time when I open up the popup window again and without clicking on the save button if I just close the popup , the data which I binded earlier to the parent page is being deleted.

Please access my [sample app here..](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-data-swap-chusj2?file=app%2Ftable.component.ts)

can anybody please help me in resolving this issue....!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are closing the dialog.ref() without emitting the results via the x button here.

```
<i class="material-icons" id="close-icon" matTooltip="Close" (click)="dialogRef.close()">close</i>
```

Changing it to the below will solve the issue, or emitting the results via the dialogRef.close(resultDataHere) will also solve the issue.

```
<i class="material-icons" id="close-icon" matTooltip="Close" (click)="saveToParentPage()">close</i>
```

**Please Note:**
If you move an item from first table to the second table and then hit x it will still save if you use saveToParentPage() or dialogRef.close(data).

- You will need to somehow keep a version of the original unmodified data in the OpenPopup class and use that.

**Revision:**

Use this to create an immutable copy of the original checked data in variable originalCheckedData

```
  data = Object.assign(ELEMENT_DATA);
  originalCheckedData = CHECKED_DATA.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));
  checkedData = Object.assign(CHECKED_DATA);
```

Then emit that original data via dialogRef.Close like this.

```
 <i class="material-icons" id="close-icon" matTooltip="Close" (click)="dialogRef.close(originalCheckedData);">close</i>
```

**Revision2:**
Gérôme Grignon is correct, it will solve the issue for clicking outside of dialog, my approach does not.

**Revision3:**
In my opinion I believe the challenge here was that you initialize ELEMENT_DATA as a const, because technically it is no longer a const, the original data is being mutated/modified... I took the following approach to solve the revert to original on cancel.

Set all CONST to VAR, because technically they are no longer CONST and it makes life easier reverting back to original data on cancel.

```
var ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
  { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
  { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' }
];

var CHECKED_DATA: Element[] = [];
```

Then change your x button to trigger cancelChange() method

```
<i class="material-icons" id="close-icon" matTooltip="Close" (click)="cancelChange()">close</i>
```

Then create immutable copies of originalData and originalCheckedData

```
data = Object.assign(ELEMENT_DATA);
originalData = ELEMENT_DATA.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));
checkedData = Object.assign(CHECKED_DATA);
originalCheckedData = CHECKED_DATA.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));
```

Then do the following in your cancelChange() method

```
cancelChange(){
   ELEMENT_DATA = this.originalData.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));;
   CHECKED_DATA = this.originalCheckedData.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));;
   this.dialogRef.close(this.originalCheckedData)
  }
```

Comment: OH.... yes i didnt notice that......!

Comment: Please see revision, I am working on how to make a non immutable copy to revert back to original

Comment: where can i find the revision....?

Comment: Please Note: section in my answer above. I am working on a fix for this.

Comment: yes its because we have taken saveToParentPage() on clicking close button also....!

Comment: correct even using this does the same dialogRef.close(data).. the key to solving this is creating an immutable copy of the data on dialog open so that when the x is clicked it overwrites any changes. Will post revision when I have this sorted.

Comment: its even working only if change it back again to previous ..............<i class="material-icons" id="close-icon" matTooltip="Close" (click)="dialogRef.close()">close</i>

Comment: y did you remove that revision....? i wanted to check that too

Comment: yes ... thanks to both of you for helping me.....

Comment: Because Gérôme Grignon solution is correct, mine worked for the x in the upper right corner but clicking outside of the dialog to close it still had the same issue.

Comment: but for that i would have disabled the closing of dialogue when clicked outside

Comment: I will re-add it for your review.

Comment: okay .... thanks again

Comment: but i do have one more issue...!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182599/discussion-between-marshal-and-heena).

Comment: when i transfer the row and close the popup ,the data which i transferred i need it to be back to first table again if i didnt save it

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion and help..... its working as expected ....!thanks again

Comment: @Marshall .... Can you please help me out with this issue....?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and resolved it adding a conditionnal statement around the result.

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log('The dialog was closed');
  console.log('from the parent component', result);
  console.log(result);
  if(result) {
    this.result = result;
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.result);
  }
```

I works too if you close the popup clicking outside it.

Comment: no its still saving the data on closing without clicking on save button

Comment: it's not saving the data : it's keeping the previous value (so even if result is null, you still keep tha current value of your parent page).

Comment: yes .... its working when we change the  line <i class="material-icons" id="close-icon" matTooltip="Close" (click)="saveToParentPage()">close</i>    ............. back again to ..................<i class="material-icons" id="close-icon" matTooltip="Close" (click)="dialogRef.close()">close</i>